# remove slash from $location.url() in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, location

I need to get the GET params from url  and pass it in the links to view in angular

I got from `location.url()`  **=>** "`/?x=1&b=2`"

but I need to get **= >** "`?x=1&b=2`"  without slash

I tried to do that like the following:

```
var str =  $location.url();
var x = str.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

but it kept the slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = $location.url().substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**: 
if you use route get the parameters with [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

you can access the params like:

```
$routeParams.x
```

**Answer to question:** 
Do it like a famous question suggests:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

To be used like:

```
var x = getParameterByName('x');
```